# How to autofill content controls based on a seperate dropdown list in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010

I have a form with multiple fields. Three of these fields are dependent on the selection chosen in a dropdown list at the top of the form.

For example:

if **Location** = New York City, then the following fields would be populated as
**CC**=0001, **Approver**= John Smith, **Tel**=(201) 555-1234

if **Location** = Miami, then
**CC**=0005, **Approver**=Jane Brown, **Tel**=(305) 555-9876

My dropdown list has 12 locations with values to populate the three fields
(Display Name: Miami; Value: 0005||Jane Brown||(305) 555-9876)

My knowledge of VBA is quite limited so I tried looking at the codes in the demonstration documentation from Greg Maxey's "Link 'Conditional Content' to a List Selection" page but the multiple methods/conditions in the documents confuse me so I'm having trouble identifying which parts of the code I need.

Comment: **if**  you have a drop down that determines it, you can create an action on the drop down selection that does different things for different **cases** - though if the fields get reset you should probably **clear** them all before **select**ing your **case**

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't know how to do that.